# Call PHP runtime functions as a linked library from C

Tags: php, c, shared-libraries

This question almost answers what I want to know: [Is it possible to call PHP's C functions in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567195/is-it-possible-to-call-phps-c-functions-in-a-c-program)

Of course you can call PHP functions from C if you compile the PHP source code with your program. But is it possible to call the PHP runtime from a C program without this, as a library?

**Edit**: I downloaded the PHP source code and compiled it. Will try to link the object files with my own code, and see if I can call it from LLVM-generated IR.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but is not a good idea. You see, php functions are meant to be used by php scripts, with their own data structures and memory management, no directly by C. There's a LOT, and I mean A LOT of macros and syntactic sugar in there just to expose a function to the parser. for example:

```
ZEND_FUNCTION(func_num_args)
{
    zend_execute_data *ex = EX(prev_execute_data);

    if (!(ZEND_CALL_INFO(ex) & ZEND_CALL_CODE)) {
        RETURN_LONG(ZEND_CALL_NUM_ARGS(ex));
    } else {
        zend_error(E_WARNING, "func_num_args():  Called from the global scope - no function context");
        RETURN_LONG(-1);
    }
}
```

These macros and support functions spans across the entire interpreter and you have to do a lot of initialization boilerplate before using it even like a shared library (eg. what is the function context?).

A simple `strlen` looks like

```
ZEND_FUNCTION(strlen)
{
    zend_string *s;

#ifndef FAST_ZPP
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "S", &s) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }
#else
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_STR(s)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();
#endif

    RETVAL_LONG(ZSTR_LEN(s));
}
```

You MUST use zend_string instead a c *string*. And you can have the same in C with just

```
size_t strlen(const char *str);
```

If you want to use php features in your application a sane alternative is just to use an embedded php interpreter like this https://github.com/symisc/PH7 (a bit abandoned but still PHP 5.3) and of course, run php code.

Paraphrasing Dr. Ian Malcom: *You were so preoccupied with whether or not you could, you didn't stop to think if you should*

Comment: In my case, I really should: I'm making a PHP LLVM backend, and need the runtime as a library so I don't have to write my own or compile it in some specific way.

Comment: But maybe there's no getting away from writing my own build system for the PHP source-code?

Comment: That changes the question. The linked source code is a good start for a frontend. Easier than hack the Zend engine and easier to plugin your LLVM backend.

Comment: Well, if you are willing to remove unnecesary parts to plugin in your backend and correctly bootstrap Zend engine (or what is left of it) then **of course** you can.